# Exponential equation involving different bases.

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Alright, I know you can get the solution $ x=2 $ just by giving the equation a glance, but I am asking for a rigorous proof here. All mathematical tools are encouraged (no *syllabus limitation*).
$$ 5^{\frac{x}{2}}-2^{x}=1$$

Comment: We are looking at $5^t-4^t$, which is $5^t(1-(4/5)^t)$, an increasing function.

Comment: Not sure if there is a really rigorous way to solve this. In general, you simply graph it on a calculator or Computer Algebra System. Looks like Andre is on track.